# Regex - Get matches of @[SomeText] in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get all matches of `@[SomeText]` pattern in a string.

For example, for this string:

here is `@[text1]` some text `@[text2]`

I want `@[text1]` and `@[text2]`.

I'm using Regex Hero to check my pattern matching online,
and my pattern works fine when there's one expression to match,

For example:

```
here is @[text1] text
```

but with more then one, I get both matches with the text in the middle.

[image]

This is my regex:

```
@\[.*\]
```

I would appreciate assistance in isolating the occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using greedy quantifier (`*`). To capture all you need, you should use lazy quantifier (`*?`) with a global modifier:

```
/(@\[.*?\])/g
```

Take a look here https://regex101.com/r/pH0gA5/1

Answer (score 1):

This should work  :

```
@\[(.*?)\]
```

**Details :**

**(.*?)** : match everything in a non-greedy way and capture it.
Because the *? quantifier is lazy (non-greedy), it matches as few characters as possible to allow the overall match attempt to succeed, i.e. `text1`. For the match attempt that starts at a given position, a lazy quantifier gives you the shortest match.

Comment: Yap, this one works. Would you mind providing a short explanation?

Comment: I've added little description now.

Answer (score 0):

.* is greedy by default, so it only finds one match, treating "text1] and @[text2" as the text between the two square brackets.

If you add a questions mark after the .* then it will find the minimum number of characters before reaching a ].

So the regex \@[.*?] do what you want.